# code::blocks wxWidgets Changing the font of a wxStaticBoxSizer

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I know that our questions put on evidence our knowledge, so be gentle please :). This is one of mine in C++. Well, here we go.

I'm trying to change from codeblocks the font of a StaticBoxSizer. I can change the font of the wxStaticBox in the properties section but I'm having a hard time finding a way to access the same thing for the wxStaticBoxSizer FROM wxSmith in codeBlocks.

I tried without success to acces the staticBox within the sizer. What's worst, i dont know how to access any of the wxSmith's elements from the code editor.

All hints are welcomed and thank you in advance.

Edit:
I know for sure that there's nothing wrong with the IDE but here's the [header](http://pastebin.com/CqsjpXVk) and here the [cpp](http://pastebin.com/pcM8iiJs).

I noticed that the sizers are not declared in the headers but in the constructor's implementation of the dialog. I try to access the sizer in the constructor but to no avail.

The links works to me but here are the contents of the files directly. I simplified the code to include the minimum of elements.

header:

```
/***************************************************************
 * Name:      sizerTestMain.h
 * Purpose:   Defines Application Frame
 * Author:    RainMaker ()
 * Created:   2015-11-11
 * Copyright: RainMaker ()
 * License:
 **************************************************************/

#ifndef SIZERTESTMAIN_H
#define SIZERTESTMAIN_H

//(*Headers(sizerTestFrame)
#include <wx/sizer.h>
#include <wx/menu.h>
#include <wx/button.h>
#include <wx/frame.h>
#include <wx/statusbr.h>
//*)

class sizerTestFrame: public wxFrame
{
    public:

        sizerTestFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id = -1);
        virtual ~sizerTestFrame();

    private:

        //(*Handlers(sizerTestFrame)
        void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnButton3Click(wxCommandEvent& event);
        //*)

        //(*Identifiers(sizerTestFrame)
        static const long ID_BUTTON1;
        static const long ID_BUTTON2;
        static const long ID_BUTTON3;
        static const long idMenuQuit;
        static const long idMenuAbout;
        static const long ID_STATUSBAR1;
        //*)

        //(*Declarations(sizerTestFrame)
        wxButton* Button1;
        wxButton* Button2;
        wxButton* Button3;
        wxStatusBar* StatusBar1;
        //*)

        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};

#endif // SIZERTESTMAIN_H
```

and this is the cpp

```
/***************************************************************
 * Name:      sizerTestMain.cpp
 * Purpose:   Code for Application Frame
 * Author:    RainMaker ()
 * Created:   2015-11-11
 * Copyright: RainMaker ()
 * License:
 **************************************************************/

#include "wx_pch.h"
#include "sizerTestMain.h"
#include <wx/msgdlg.h>

//(*InternalHeaders(sizerTestFrame)
#include <wx/intl.h>
#include <wx/string.h>
//*)

//helper functions
enum wxbuildinfoformat {
    short_f, long_f };

wxString wxbuildinfo(wxbuildinfoformat format)
{
    wxString wxbuild(wxVERSION_STRING);

    if (format == long_f )
    {
#if defined(__WXMSW__)
        wxbuild << _T("-Windows");
#elif defined(__UNIX__)
        wxbuild << _T("-Linux");
#endif

#if wxUSE_UNICODE
        wxbuild << _T("-Unicode build");
#else
        wxbuild << _T("-ANSI build");
#endif // wxUSE_UNICODE
    }

    return wxbuild;
}

//(*IdInit(sizerTestFrame)
const long sizerTestFrame::ID_BUTTON1 = wxNewId();
const long sizerTestFrame::ID_BUTTON2 = wxNewId();
const long sizerTestFrame::ID_BUTTON3 = wxNewId();
const long sizerTestFrame::idMenuQuit = wxNewId();
const long sizerTestFrame::idMenuAbout = wxNewId();
const long sizerTestFrame::ID_STATUSBAR1 = wxNewId();
//*)

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(sizerTestFrame,wxFrame)
    //(*EventTable(sizerTestFrame)
    //*)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

sizerTestFrame::sizerTestFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id)
{
    //(*Initialize(sizerTestFrame)
    wxMenuItem* MenuItem2;
    wxMenuItem* MenuItem1;
    wxMenu* Menu1;
    wxStaticBoxSizer* theSizer;
    wxMenuBar* MenuBar1;
    wxFlexGridSizer* FlexGridSizer1;
    wxMenu* Menu2;

    Create(parent, id, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, _T("id"));
    FlexGridSizer1 = new wxFlexGridSizer(0, 3, 0, 0);
    theSizer = new wxStaticBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL, this, _("I want to change this title"));
    Button1 = new wxButton(this, ID_BUTTON1, _("with this"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON1"));
    theSizer->Add(Button1, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    Button2 = new wxButton(this, ID_BUTTON2, _("or this"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON2"));
    theSizer->Add(Button2, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    FlexGridSizer1->Add(theSizer, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    Button3 = new wxButton(this, ID_BUTTON3, _("Or this"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON3"));
    FlexGridSizer1->Add(Button3, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    SetSizer(FlexGridSizer1);
    MenuBar1 = new wxMenuBar();
    Menu1 = new wxMenu();
    MenuItem1 = new wxMenuItem(Menu1, idMenuQuit, _("Quit\tAlt-F4"), _("Quit the application"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    Menu1->Append(MenuItem1);
    MenuBar1->Append(Menu1, _("&File"));
    Menu2 = new wxMenu();
    MenuItem2 = new wxMenuItem(Menu2, idMenuAbout, _("About\tF1"), _("Show info about this application"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    Menu2->Append(MenuItem2);
    MenuBar1->Append(Menu2, _("Help"));
    SetMenuBar(MenuBar1);
    StatusBar1 = new wxStatusBar(this, ID_STATUSBAR1, 0, _T("ID_STATUSBAR1"));
    int __wxStatusBarWidths_1[1] = { -1 };
    int __wxStatusBarStyles_1[1] = { wxSB_NORMAL };
    StatusBar1->SetFieldsCount(1,__wxStatusBarWidths_1);
    StatusBar1->SetStatusStyles(1,__wxStatusBarStyles_1);
    SetStatusBar(StatusBar1);
    FlexGridSizer1->Fit(this);
    FlexGridSizer1->SetSizeHints(this);

    Connect(ID_BUTTON1,wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&sizerTestFrame::OnButton1Click);
    Connect(ID_BUTTON3,wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&sizerTestFrame::OnButton3Click);
    Connect(idMenuQuit,wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&sizerTestFrame::OnQuit);
    Connect(idMenuAbout,wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&sizerTestFrame::OnAbout);
    //*)
}

sizerTestFrame::~sizerTestFrame()
{
    //(*Destroy(sizerTestFrame)
    //*)
}

void sizerTestFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close();
}

void sizerTestFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxString msg = wxbuildinfo(long_f);
    wxMessageBox(msg, _("Welcome to..."));
}

void sizerTestFrame::OnButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
}

void sizerTestFrame::OnButton3Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
{

}
```

Comment: Show us the code; **paste the snippet into your question**.  I don't believe your issues is with the codeBlocks IDE, but with your code.

Comment: I edited the question to add the files. That was a fast response btw.

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't *paste the snippet into your question*, but you pasted *a link instead*.  Try again, it can't be difficult to highlight your code, copy to the clipboard, edit your question, and paste the code from the clipboard.

Comment: It sounds an awful lot like you're trying to set the font and size of a piece of paper,which clearly, one cannot do. Instead, one assigns font information to _the strings_ on the page. Since the sizer doesn't actually contain text, but may contain objects that hold text, I'd be looking at setting _their_ fonts (not those of the parent that contains them. A quick play with the tool and my memory seems revived - Set the size of the elements, no the containers. Also, you may prefer `wxFormBuilder` I tried it years ago and never looked back to the WX 'toy' that C::B contains.

Comment: Thank you for your hints enhzflep. It makes a lot of sense and is what I started trying to do. I arrived to this conclusion of changing the font of the sizer after reading the wx docs. I am really tempted with wxFormBuilder but I like wxSmith so far. If I find a problem with the tool and not the user, wxFormBuilder will be my next choice.

Comment: @RainMaker - you're welcome. I'd investigate wxFormBuilder anyway, if I were you. It offers a far more WYSIWYG experience and makes it far easier (and in some cases, possible) to perform some actions. WxSmith forces you to do some things in the code, wxFormBuilder offers config options, it's also made by the people that make WX.. It's only a couple of meg to download. The only complaint I've had is that I could neither get an package for, nor build it for a RasPi,though programs written on either a Win or a *nix box still compile and run fine on the Pi - the form builder itself simply doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem ! !
This is what did.

1 - I noticed that the sizer was not included in the header so I looked for the ways to include it from wxSmith. **The magic came from the "isMember" checkBox in the properties table.** It seems that this is the way of including it to the header and then accessing it.

2 - I created a member function at the end of the constructor:

```
void IbDialogue::setFonts();
```

3 - In the function implementation, I accessed the wxStaticBox of the wxStaticBoxSizer and set it like this:

```
wxFont* nf = new wxFont;
StaticBoxSizer7->GetStaticBox()->SetFont(nf->Bold());
```

And VOILÀ the font is mastered ! ! !

```
for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
cout<<(HA HA HA HA);
```